# Connect to Redis server from within a Docker image

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, stunnel

I have 2 hosts, a web unit (WU) and a computing unit (CU). On the WU, I have my website. On the CU, I have a redis server and a (C++) app that does some computing.

The user enters input data in the website, and then I want to enqueue a job from the WU to the Redis server on the CU. I have then a worker on the CU which performs a task.

Now, I am able to enqueue a job from the WU (outside of any docker image) to the CU from the terminal (using the python  `rq` module). However, my website is in a docker image, and I can't get it working. From within the docker image, I try to connect to 172.17.0.1:6370 (172.17.0.1 is the IP of the gateway between the image and the docker host). The error I get is *connection refused*. Then I thought I might have to map the ports in my docker-compose file: 6739:6739. However, then I got an error saying the port is already used. And indeed, it is used by the stunnel4 service which allows me to enqueue jobs from the WU to the redis server on the CU.

Should I run the stunnel4 service in the docker image are something? And if so, how could I do that? Or should I tackle my problem in a different way?

**Network structure**

WU and CU are 2 (virtual) machines. My redis server is on CU and **not** in a docker container. I am able to connect to the redis server from WU to CU by means of the python redis module (but not from within a docker container). I had to set up a `stunnel4.service` for that (redis-client on WU and redis-server on CU).

Comment: Does your Redis run in docker? Are they in the same machine? If not, how do you connect to CU host from your WU host without considering Docker? (Please describe your network structure)

Comment: @AliTou I added info on my network structure.

Comment: I think the best solution might be to run a stunnel service in the docker image on WU. If I manage to get it working I'll post an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I managed to build a stunnel service in a docker container on the WU. I can now simply connect with `python redis` to that stunnel service, and the end of the tunnel points to the CU.

Here is what I did on the WU:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.12
RUN apk add --no-cache stunnel
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./ca_file.crt /etc/stunnel/ca_file.crt
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /etc/stunnel

cat > stunnel.conf <<_EOF_

foreground = yes

[stunnel-client]
client = yes
accept = ${ACCEPT}
connect = ${CONNECT}
CAfile = ca_file.crt
verify = 4

_EOF_

exec stunnel "$@"
```

The `ACCEPT` and `CONNECT` values are specified in an environment file:

**.env.stunnel**

```
ACCEPT=6379
CONNECT=10.110.0.3:6379
```

where `10.110.0.3` is the IP address of my redis host.

**docker-compose**

```
stunnel-client:
    container_name: stunnel-client
    build:
      context: ./stunnel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - stunnel_volume:/etc/stunnel
    env_file:
      - ./.env.stunnel
    networks:
      - stunnel-net
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

The `stunnel-net` is also in my `web` service so I can connect from there to the `stunnel-client` service by means of `python redis`.

Comment: If somebody has a more elegant solution to my problem, I will gladly choose that one as the accepted answer instead of my own.